# ng-click Vs click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a website based on angular js.

Currently, I have written about 5000 line code in angular js.

So I have to make some changes without touching my angular js.

I want something like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#buttonid',function(){

  //performing some necessary task then call ng-click method 
  ngclickmethod();

});
```

HTML Code:

```
<a ng-click="ngclickmethod()" id="buttonid">
```

Please advise how can I achieve that.

Many Thanks

Comment: Your button's click event (registered by angular) will be executed regardless, angular also just register the handler. And in this case you are getting the event when bubbled to the document. So angular click handler will most possibly get executed. Can you provide some practical scenario? Anyways you just have to do `angular.element(this).scope().ngclickmethod()`

Comment: Yes, that's my point, I want to execute click event first and then ng-click event. I already have register handler for the method

Comment: Then you should not use event delegation. You should register the event directly on the element. http://plnkr.co/edit/O25ZXZCcgZGss7O29ULt?p=preview .So basically you would have to keep the script tag on your html which has this anchor tag and bind the event to it.

Comment: can I disable ng-click until I perform some necessary operation, then enable and execute ng-click method?

Comment: So code will be look like this right?
$(document).on('click','#buttonid',function(){

  //performing some necessary task then call ng-click method 
  angular.element(this).scope().ngclickmethod()

});

Comment: That won't work as far as i know (_Events are bubbled up, binding event on document will happen only after the click event on the element_). See my previous comments and my link. You just keep the click event on the html where your anchor tag is, bind it directly, see my demo. Also do you have any async operations that you do inside the handler outside?

Comment: See this example, if you are doing any async operations.. http://plnkr.co/edit/7zbjAKmUsxLRqjfAH1qC?p=preview

Comment: Thanks PSL, that code is working.

Comment: Just curious did it work with registering the event using document itself? or you moved the script to the html and had the click event bound directly on the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you are trying to call an angular function outside of angular. Try this..

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('yourControllerElementID')).scope().ngclickmethod();
```

this will call the method you want. Be sure the controller element ID is the controller that contains the ngclickmethod function

Comment: Ya...This code is working ...Thanks everybody taking the part of this discussion...